# HTML - Scrollbar for table?

Tags: html, css

So have system: https://jsfiddle.net/o6xf5a6d/

The problem with that is, if I added `overflow:scroll` to `<tbody>` then nothing happens.. How could I fix that?

Comment: Could you post the code from the fiddle here as well? That is generally preferred on this site, as we can see it more readily and can detect many problems a little quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o6xf5a6d/1/

Add overflow: scroll; to the modal.

```
#myModal {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I had it, but I wanted that scroll only to the body where items are in.

Comment: Try this, https://jsfiddle.net/o6xf5a6d/2/, the added CSS is at the top, check it out.

Comment: Thanks Sir! That's perfect :). Maybe I can ask one more thing. As you can see in table each item which are `added` to the table are same color. Is there possibility adding first line which is added there example is grey, 2nd is white 3rd is grey etc.

Comment: If you use Bootstrap then you just need to add the class ".table-striped" to the table. Otherwise, this link might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121144/alternating-row-colors-in-bootstrap-3-no-table

Comment: Hmm okay, btw, that scroll can that be for `body` so it only is for the items which are added. So If I scroll, then the Item, condition price wont move with them.

Answer (score 0):

Set a div around your table and set the max-height property and then put overflow to  scrolling for the div.